# Exporting Layers to Cad with Seed file Changes size and Location On ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, autocad, dwg

Some background information before I go into the issue. I am working on project 
that takes place in Erie county New York. The shapefiles consist of 2 line layers and 2 point layers. The files were exported as a KML and converted into shapefiles with WGS 84. When I export those files to CAD it works fine and lines up properly.

I was using Orbit to export the points and it does not add a coordinate system but somehow line up where they should but only when I added an ersi basemap first. When I try exporting the layers to cad the blocks are in different places around the world.

When I Export the cad file with a seed file attached the exported DWG changes size and position. ArcMap sends it to the Dominican Republic. The converted file appears tiny and the blocks are on top each other with the parcel data in the middle.

I have tried changing the coordinate system of the cad file and have even tried exporting the polyline as a shapefile to  WGS 84 and WGS  83 zone 18n and changing the mapping units to no avail.

[image]

[image]